# Negative feedback in eBay

Tags: ebay

Is there a "safe" way to give negative feedback in eBay? Sometimes I get across other people who should get a negative, but at the same time I don't want to ruin my own feedback (yes, I know its antisocial attitude) - so I just don't give them any feedback. Is there a way to give them negative but protect myself?

Comment: Bear in mind that sellers cannot leave negative or neutral feedback anymore, only positive feedback. Only buyers can leave negative feedback.

Comment: @PhonicUK, is that really true? This would mean that giving negative feedback is always safe (if you are a buyer). And what if a buyer fails to pay for the items, delays the process, etc. - what was the rationale behind prohibiting the seller to leave negative feedback?

Comment: Yup - it was done quite a long time ago as well. They stopped allowing sellers to leave negative feedback because they were using it vindictively to spite buyers who left negative feedback. If the buyer doesn't pay then there are still ways of reporting this and it's dealt with appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only method I know is to sell so many items that the negative feedback is drowned out by the positive.  I've seen this effect looking at some high-volume sellers that sell over a hundred items per day.